# VS2010: change document tab order w/ keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have three documents open in VS2010.  There are three tabs in the tab well.

Can I change the order by which those tabs are displayed using only my keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The only supported method for changing the tabbing order in the default Visual Studio install is to drag them into the desired order with the mouse.